# Can’t search for Synaptic on GNOME Shell

Tags: gnome, synaptic

“Activities” view of GNOME Shell does not show up results of administrative applications, such as Synaptic. To run it, you have to use Alt+F2. I’m using it in Oneiric. Do I have to do another thing?

Answer (score 3):

This problem is gone --just was a incorrect `OnlyShowIn` setting. Now it works.